# How to control how many times something is shown in Processing?

Tags: processing

```
void setup() {
  background(0);
  fullScreen();
}

void draw() {
  int g = 0;
  float cCount = map(mouseY, 0, height, 1, 20);
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i+=50) {
    while(g < cCount) {
     circle(i, mouseY, 20); 
    }
  }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is change the number of times circles are shown on the screen as I move the mouse. When the mouse moves down, more circles are shown on the screen all with the same Y coordinate but the distance between each circle is 50. As I move the mouse up, less circles are shown. Max circles is 20 and min is 1. I don't know how to set up a way for the number of circles to change as I move the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct, but your code has some bugs that are not related to the problem itself.

In your `while (g < cCount)` loop, neither `g` nor `cCount` is updated, resulting in an infinite loop, but you don't really need that while loop anyway.

The following should work (but I haven't checked running the code myself, so it might have some bugs.

```
void draw() {
  int circleCount = round(map(mouseY, 0, height, 1, 20));
  for (int i = 0; i < circleCount; i+=1) {
   circle(i*50, mouseY, 20); 
  }
}
```